# Adding/removing classes to/from objects in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just to be sure I got it right...

```
myArray.removeClass('className');
```

will remove the class named "className" from ALL objects added to that array, yes?

ADDENDUM:

```
    <div id="parentEle">
        <div id="ele1"></div>
        <div id="ele2"></div>
    </div>

    #ele1 {
        //CSS
    }
    #ele1.className {
        //CSS
    }
    #ele2 {
        //CSS
    }
    #ele2.className {
        //CSS
    }

    var myArray = [];
    $('div','#parentEle').each(function() {
        myArray.push($(this)); 
    });

    // now to remove the class from both...
```

Comment: No, it'd throw a `TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'removeClass'`. Are you actually talking about jQuery instead?

Comment: oops, you're right. Yes this is for jQ, does that mean I have to use .each() or something?

Comment: Is this a "real" jQuery object or is this just an array (for example `$('.class')` vs `[$('.class')[0], $('.class')[1]`)? They are two different things. Anyway, if it is actually a jQuery object it will work as expected.

Comment: Why are you *asking* this, instead of *trying* this? You could have just read the API for the [`removeClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and answered this yourself.

Comment: clarified question...

Comment: You want to remove a class-name that the elements don't have?

Comment: @DavidThomas  ...because I'm under the gun to get things required of me done and as much as I'd like to learn all details along the way, it's not something I can do now. I'm simply asking for help.

Comment: @DavidThomas the classes are assigned through code elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you use JQuery's selector and this is your array([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wfbq/)):

```
var myArray = $('span');
myArray.removeClass('active');
```

Else, you get:

> TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'removeClass'

However, using each([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wfbq/1/)):

```
var myArray = [$('span').first(), $('span').first(), $('span').first()]; // selecting first element 3 times

$.each(myArray, function () {
    this.removeClass();
});
```

You can get expected results.

**Update(to your needs) - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wfbq/2/):**

```
$(function () { // execute when the page's loaded
    var myArray = $('#parentEle div'); // select all divs inside #parentEle element
    $.each(myArray, function () { // iterate over selected divs
        $(this).removeClass('className'); // remove class
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, given the ambiguities, and lack of clarity, in the question:

```
var myArray = $('#parentEle div').map(function(){
    return this;
}).get();

$.each(myArray, function(i,e){
    $(e).removeClass('className');
});
```

Coupled with the HTML:

```
<div id="parentEle">
    <div id="ele1" class="className">ele1</div>
    <div id="ele2" class="className">ele2</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F63a9/).

Or, in plain JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.className'), function(a){
    a.classList.remove('className');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F63a9/1/).

Comment: Thanks. your first approach did what I was looking for